# Cassandra timestamp is not accurate?

Tags: java, cassandra, timestamp, cql

I am using cassandra-maven-plugin with Maven failsafe to perform TestNG integration test for a class that handles Cassandra-related operations.

While trying to find why my queries for a column of type timestamp always fail; I noticed something weird. At first, dates that I am using as a parameter and the date retrieved from Cassandra looked like the same, I was formatting them as a String to compare.

But when I compared them in milliseconds, I noticed that Cassandra date is ~1000 milliseconds ahead of the Date I use for query.

Then I directly used milliseconds to set the row's timestamp value, yet Cassandra returned a date with some extra milliseconds again.

Question is, is this a known bug?

Now I am going to use a String or Long representation of date to fix this; but I want to know what is going on?

Thanks!

Edit: I am running tests using Windows 8.1.

Here's my (somewhat sanitized) data set file that is loaded to the embedded Cassandra:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS analytics WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.events (id text, name text, start_time timestamp, end_time timestamp, parameters map<text,text>, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.errors (id text, message text, time timestamp, parameters map<text,text>, PRIMARY KEY (id, time));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.reports (name text, time timestamp, period int, data blob, PRIMARY KEY (name, period));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics.user_preferences (company_id text, user_principal text, opted_in boolean, PRIMARY KEY (company_id, user_principal));

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS event_name ON analytics.events (name);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS report_time ON analytics.reports (time);

INSERT INTO analytics.user_preferences (company_id, user_principal, opted_in) VALUES ('company1', 'user1', true);
INSERT INTO analytics.user_preferences (company_id, user_principal, opted_in) VALUES ('company3', 'user3', false);

INSERT INTO analytics.reports (name, time, period, data) VALUES ('com.example.SomeReport1', null, 3, null);
INSERT INTO analytics.reports (name, time, period, data) VALUES ('com.example.SomeReport2', 1296691200000, 1, null);
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM analytics.reports WHERE name = ? AND period = ? AND time = ? LIMIT 1;
```

When I get the time field with row.getDate("time") it has those extra milliseconds.

Comment: It might help to see your schema and insert/read queries (sanitized, if needed), so someone can try to reproduce the behavior. Could be clock skew or timestamp precision difference, perhaps?

Comment: Which OS are you using for testing?

Comment: Edited to clarify the points you asked. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem `row.getDate("time").getTime()` returns 1296691200000 (which is the expected value). Which Cassandra version and driver version are you using?